# restrict page callback url?

Tags: 7

With this callback code - is it possible to restrict url just to be example/page1 (2 arg) but not example/page1/321 or example/page1/abc/efg...?

```
// hook_menu example
function example_menu() {
 $items['example/page1'] = array(
'page callback'     => 'example_page1_callback',
'access callback'   => TRUE,
'type'              => MENU_CALLBACK,
 );
 return $items;
  }

 // hook_meny callback function
function example_page1_callback() {
 // please provide code within this function to turn these next three
  // variables into separate output variables for the template.
  $variable_to_print1 = 'Foo';
  $variable_to_print2 = 'Bar';
  $variable_to_print3 = array('bing', 'bang', 'bong');
  return;
 }
```

Comment: That's what the access callback can be used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be within your code.

You could change your `'access callback' => TRUE,` to a function e.g. `'access callback' => my_access_check,`

And within that function you can have an if statement to detect if a 2nd arg existing and if it does return false which would provide an access denied

If you wanted to do a "page not found" or a redirect or something else then you could put this logic into your `'example_page1_callback'` function